# Parsing CSV to template in python

Tags: python, csv

I want to write simple python script which will first load .csv file and then output it to another file using provided template:

```
FirstVariable Cleartext-Password := "SecondVariable", Service-Type := Framed-User
    Framed-IP-Address := ThirdVariable,
    MS-Primary-DNS-Server := 8.8.8.8,
    Fall-Through = Yes,
    Mikrotik-Rate-Limit = 4thVariableM/5thVariableM
```

example:

input file:

```
john;lovelycat;192.168.1.1;40;30
```

output:

```
john Cleartext-Password := "lovelycat", Service-Type := Framed-User
    Framed-IP-Address := 192.168.1.1,
    MS-Primary-DNS-Server := 8.8.8.8,
    Fall-Through = Yes,
    Mikrotik-Rate-Limit = 40M/30M
```

Other parameters above should stay as they are, i only need to paste the mentioned values.

At this moment i know only how to read and write files, but i have no clue how to tell python to output text to file and how to use variables in the text so i can save the parameters from .csv to variables and then output it.

Could you please help me with tips how can i accomplish it?

Comment: where is the template?

Comment: @deadshot Sorry, edited

Comment: You can use [f-Strings](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/lexical_analysis.html#f-strings) ([PEP](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0498/)), for example. Or [Jinja2](https://jinja.palletsprojects.com/en/2.11.x/) as a more complex templating system. I would recommend to delete that question, try a bit with string formatting and/or templating and ask another question if you have something more to show (code) (or edit this question instead of deleting)

Comment: @colidyre Thank you Sir, checking Jinja2 right now.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using `csv` module with `f-string`

**Ex:**

```
import csv


with open(filename) as infile:
    reader = csv.reader(infile, delimiter=";")
    for row in reader:
        template_data = f"""{row[0]} Cleartext-Password := "{row[1]}", Service-Type := Framed-User
                    Framed-IP-Address := {row[2]},
                    MS-Primary-DNS-Server := 8.8.8.8,
                    Fall-Through = Yes,
                    Mikrotik-Rate-Limit = {row[3]}M/{row[4]}M"""
        print(template_data)
```

**Output:**

```
john Cleartext-Password := "lovelycat", Service-Type := Framed-User
                    Framed-IP-Address := 192.168.1.1,
                    MS-Primary-DNS-Server := 8.8.8.8,
                    Fall-Through = Yes,
                    Mikrotik-Rate-Limit = 40M/30M
```